# Uniformly Most Powerful test for discrete distribution

Tags: self-learning, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Let $X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n$ be iid random variables having pdf

$$f_X(x\mid\theta) =\theta^{2}(1 -\theta)^{x}$$

where $$x\in\{ 0,1,... \}$$

I want test this hypothesis using UMP test:

$$H_0:\theta=\theta_0\space vs \space H_1:\theta >\theta_1$$

By Neyman–Pearson lemma where the test is of the type and the
pdf is $f(x|\theta)$ with critical region $R$ is $x\in R$ if
$\frac{f(x|\theta_1)}{f(x|\theta_0)}>k$ and $x\in R^c$ if
$\frac{f(x|\theta_1)}{f(x|\theta_0)}<k$ for any $k\geq 0$ and
$\alpha=P_{\theta_0}(X\in R)$

$$ \frac{f(x|\theta_1)}{f(x|\theta_0)}>k$$
$$\frac{\theta_{1}^{2n}  (1-\theta_{1})^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}} }{\theta_{0}^{2n}  (1-\theta_{0})^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}}}>k$$

$$\left(\frac{\theta_{1}}{\theta_{0}}  \right)^{2n} \, \left(\frac{1-\theta_{1}}{1-\theta_{0}}  \right)^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}} > k $$

Therefore, $$ {\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} < k_{1}}$$

Let us assume that I wanted to find the power of $\theta$ using the normal approximation. At this point, I do not know what is the distribution of $X$. If I were to find the expectation and variance of the above distribution it will be somehow complicated i.e 
$$ \mathbb{E}(X)= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \theta^{2} x (1-\theta)^{x}=1-\theta \, \,  \text{when} \, \,  |1 - \theta|<1$$

$$\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \theta^2 x^2 (1 - \theta)^x = \frac{(\theta^2 - 3 \theta + 2)}{\theta} \, \,  \text{when} \, \,  |1 - \theta|<1$$

But I was hoping if it belongs to a well-known distribution or that there is a better approach to this problem.

Comment: Did you write the pmf correctly?

Comment: Sorry, it was not in the correct format. I had plus sign instead of the minus. Thanks!!

Comment: Unfortunately, It is correct! $\theta^2$

Comment: If it was $\theta$, it would be geometric distribution!

Comment: But $\sum_{x=0}^\infty \theta^2(1-\theta)^x=\theta\ne 1$ for $|1-\theta|<1$.

Comment: Do you mean that sum over the support equals 1 should be satisfied otherwise it would violate properties of a probability mass function. That makes sense to me, probably the materials that I am looking at has a typo in it.

Comment: Consider providing an answer if you have solved this assuming a geometric distribution.